# Android emulator hangs on start-up

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator

I'm trying to use android emulator on a Linux 64 ( kernel 3.10.0 ) with kvm

```
Android emulator version 22.3.0 (build_id OPENMASTER-887826)
```

The problem is that most of the time the emulator hangs on startup. The screen is black (don't reach the google logo to appear) and the CPU of my PC show no activity. I have waited many minutes but nothing happen.

I say "most of the times" because if I reboot the PC and restart the emulator sometimes it start well (same command line options), and android boot very fast in less than a minute.

The command line I use for launch the emulator is:

```
emulator -verbose -avd nx4 -scale 0.50 -qemu -m 512 -enable-kvm
```

I have tryed disable host GPU  acceleration but with no effect.

I paste here the output of the emulator (when it hangs)

```
emulator: found SDK root at /opt/android-sdk-update-manager
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /home/fbn/.android/avd/nx4.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /home/fbn/.android/avd/nx4.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /home/fbn/.android/avd/nx4.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /home/fbn/.android/avd/nx4.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 18
emulator: 'magic' skin format detected: 768x1280
emulator: autoconfig: -skin 768x1280
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir (null)
emulator: keyset loaded from: /home/fbn/.android/default.keyset
emulator: found magic skin width=768 height=1280 bpp=16

emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/system-images/android-18/x86//kernel-qemu
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/system-images/android-18/x86//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/system-images/android-18/x86//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /home/fbn/.android/avd/nx4.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /home/fbn/.android/avd/nx4.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /home/fbn/.android/avd/nx4.avd/cache.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 1024MB

Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = x86
  hw.ramSize = 1024
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = no
  hw.trackBall = no
  hw.keyboard = yes
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = no
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = no
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = /home/fbn/.android/avd/nx4.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 768
  hw.lcd.height = 1280
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 320
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = yes
  hw.camera.back = none
  hw.camera.front = webcam0
  vm.heapSize = 64
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  hw.useext4 = no
  kernel.path = /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/system-images/android-18/x86//kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1
  disk.ramdisk.path = /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/system-images/android-18/x86//ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/system-images/android-18/x86//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 296m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /home/fbn/.android/avd/nx4.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 211m
  avd.name = nx4
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/opt/android-sdk-update-manager/tools/emulator64-x86"
emulator: argv[01] = "-m"
emulator: argv[02] = "512"
emulator: argv[03] = "-enable-kvm"
emulator: argv[04] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[05] = "/home/fbn/.android/avd/nx4.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/tools/emulator64-x86 -m 512 -enable-kvm -android-hw /home/fbn/.android/avd/nx4.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x12800000,initfile=/opt/android-sdk-update-manager/system-images/android-18/x86//system.img
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to /tmp/android-fbn/emulator-5L1wHA
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now 12819000

emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0xd300000,file=/home/fbn/.android/avd/nx4.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now d305000

emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '64m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '320'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'none'
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/home/fbn/.android/avd/nx4.avd/cache.img
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=1 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
emulator:     trying to find: /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/tools/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/tools/lib/pc-bios/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/tools/vgabios-cirrus.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/tools/lib/pc-bios/vgabios-cirrus.bin

emulator: Could not open file: (null)/system/build.prop: No such file or directory
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server
emulator: ping program: /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/tools/ddms
emulator: ping command: /opt/android-sdk-update-manager/tools/ddms ping emulator 22.3.0 "NVIDIA Corporation" "GeForce GTS 450/PCIe/SSE2" "4.4.0 NVIDIA 331.20"
emulator: User-config was not changed.
```

Comment: I have the same issue. It just hangs on the following line: "emulator: ping command: /home/eholst/Android/sdk/tools/ddms ping emulator 22.3.0 "NVIDIA Corporation" "Quadro K2000/PCIe/SSE2" "4.4.0 NVIDIA 331.20""

Comment: you have to report this issue
http://goo.gl/7RGkXH